# WCF behavior extensions

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to create a custom behavior extensions to set the credentials. But, as many other I get the load exception telling me that it could not load the specificed extension. I'm quite sure that the full qualified name is spelled correctly.

```
<extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="UserNameClientCredentials" type="Namespace.UserNameClientCredentials, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

Refered like this:

```
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="basicAuthenticationBehavior">
            <UserNameClientCredentials UserName="test" Password="tttttt"/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

And from the Endpoint:

```
<endpoint address="https://localhost:8080" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding" 
          contract="MyContract" name="endpointName"
          behaviorConfiguration="basicAuthenticationBehavior"/>
```

This will result in the following exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' in System.Configuration.dll

Additional information: The type .......  registered for extension 'UserNameClientCredentials' could not be loaded.
```

What I've tried with no luck:

1. Added the assembly to the Common7/IDE folder
2. Made sure that the DLL are located in the same directory as the executable. I even decomplied it with dotPeek to make sure that the class is there!
3. Running without Visual Studio 2015 Premium, as someone pointed out, it might be a bug in VS.

Any suggestions or alternatives to set the ClientCredentials from the config file?